# Changing highest and lowest value of image using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to change the highest and the lowest value of raster image. I want it to have the highest value of 345 and the lowest of 0. The highest value of original image now is 265 and the lowest is 0.02.

Is there any way to do this using ArcGIS?

Comment: Do you just want to change the highest and lowest values or do you want to fit all values to the new range?

Comment: Thank you MappaGnosis. I'll try to explain its purpose. It may help you make sense. I just want to use it to prepare a layout file which include 8 images on a single page with only one legend. But max and min values of every  images are not same. If it is possible, I want the values to be the same with original values without changing them. Is there any way to set false highest and lowest value.

Answer (score 1):

You can change any value within a raster by [reclassifying](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Reclassify/009z000000sr000000/) it.  There will be a similar approach in any GIS. Changing single values as per your use-case in ArcGIS does work best on integer rasters where it is straight forward, but it is possible with a little slight of hand on floating point ones too.

Basically, call up the reclassify tool and if your raster has statistics, it will automatically populate a load of fields and suggest values in the range 0-255.  If your raster does not have statistics, you may need to run the [Calculate Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m3000000) tool for reclassify to work.  In an integer rasters, just delete all the entries you are not interested in and give a new value to the max and min entries.  However, if you do that with a floating point raster, ArcGIS seems to treat this as a range, even though the two values are in separate rows in the reclassify tool.  This is where your slight of hand comes in.  Have one entry for your min value then two more rows plus a fourth for your max.  Set the the reclassification for your min value.  Then set the next row to be identical to your next value in the raster.  The third entry should be identical to a little less than your max and the fourth row is your new max value.  In your case do something like this:

0.02 = 0
0.03 = 0.03
264.99 = 264.99
265 = 345

This will then set the min and max values but force the range in between to stay the same.  I have a feeling you may need to use the exact existing values for the range between min and max to avoid a subtle spreading within your range.  It's been a while since I needed to hack a reclassification in this way and I don't have ArcGIS to hand to do a repeat test, but I do recall having to fiddle about a bit to get the desired result but you get the gist.